# How will the filter size affect the transpose convolution operation?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, pytorch, hyper-parameters, filters, transpose-convolution

After a series of convolutions, I am up-sampling a compressed representation, I was curious what is the methodology I should follow to choose an optimum kernel size for up-sampling.

1. How will the filter (or kernel) size affect the transpose convolution operation (e.g. when using [`ConvTranspose2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d.html))? Will a larger kernel help upsample with better detail or a small-sized kernel? And how would padding fit in this scenario?
2. At what rate should the depth(Channels i.e number of filters) decrease while upsampling i.e from (Dx24x24) to (D/2 or D/4, 48, 48)
   Eg: If i/p to TransposeConvolution is (cxhxw)64x8x8 how o/p quality be different for o/p of shape 32x16x16 and 16x16x16?

Comment: Would you specify the purpose of up sampling and what final expected output of your convolution, thanks.

Comment: @CloudCho I was looking for more of a general approach, so that while applying transpose convolution I could chose these hyperparameters more decisively.

Comment: thanks for details. How about Depth Decrease? Would you add more details in the question?

Comment: @CloudCho I have edited the question.

Comment: Take a look at an [article](https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/) on a similar topic.